# nvcc fatal : Value 'sm_61' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture' error with theano

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, theano, nvcc

I was setting up python and theano for use with gpu on;
ubuntu 14.04, 
GeForce GTX 1080
already installed NVIDIA driver (367.27) and CUDA toolkit (7.5) successfully for the system,
but on testing with theano gpu implementation I get the above error (for example; when importing theano with gpu enabled)
I have tried to look for possible solutions but didn't succeed.
I'm a little new to ubuntu and gpu programming, so I would appreciate any insight into how I can solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: You would need to switch to CUDA 8.0RC which supports that particular compile option, or else change the theano configuration to not compile for your GTX 1080 GPU type.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the second option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem (since I still want to use CUDA 7.5) by including the following line in the .theanorc file

```
flags = -arch=sm_52
```

no more nvcc fatal error

Answer (score 8):

As Robert Crovella said, SM 6.1 (sm_61) is only supported in CUDA 8.0 and above, and thus you should download CUDA 8.0 Release Candidate from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Ubuntu 14.04 is supported, and the instructions on the website on how to setup should be straightforward (copy and paste lines to the console).

I would also recommend downloading CUDA 8.0 when it comes out, since the RC is not the final version.